# Duplicate entry for key during SELECT statement?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

The 'duplicate entry... for key...' error message would be self-explanatory, were it not occurring during a SELECT statement rather than an INSERT.

Here is the statement: `SELECT DISTINCT e FROM EmailAddress e WHERE e.email = :email`

Here is the full code block:

```
        TypedQuery<EmailAddress> query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "SELECT DISTINCT e FROM EmailAddress e WHERE e.email = :email", EmailAddress.class);
        query.setParameter("email", email);

        try {
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
```

I'm using Hibernate with Spring. My guess is that it's something to do with the way Hibernate handles transactions. There must be something going on that I'm unaware of, because I don't think that this query alone should throw this error. However the error is definitely thrown when this query is executed.

Am I right in thinking that this must only occur during an INSERT?

If I remove this query from the path of execution, everything works fine until an insert is attempted. Then the same error is thrown.

Perhaps there is something wrong with my entities before the SELECT is executed?

If it's any help, the key in this case is a non-primary composite key residing in a join table between users and email address tables.

Comment: *Perhaps there is something wrong with my entities*. Maybe, but as you haven't posted them whih can tell? *If it's any help, the key in this case is a non-primary composite key residing in a join table between users and email address tables*. Post the relevant code rather than describing it.

Comment: On query Hibernate will flush any pending changes where necessary in order to ensure the query returns accurate results. So, most likely you have a new Email instance not yet persisted at the time of the query and which is flushed before the query is executed.

Comment: @AlanHay - Thanks, that helps. I think that may be the root of the problem. I didn't post the code because I don't own it.